# How to synchronize actions between it blocks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I'm using protractor to run e2e tests on my angular app.

I want to be able to synchronize actions between `describe` or `it` blocks like:

```
describe('My spec', function () {
  doMyAction();

  describe('My sub spec 1', function () {
    ...
  });

  describe('My sub spec 2', function () {
    ...
  });

  doAnotherAction();
});
```

The problem is these actions are executed in this order:

1. doMyAction
2. doAnotherAction
3. describe1
4. describe2

Is there a way to force the describe blocks to be executed before `doAnotherAction`?
I checked the control flow feature: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Control_Flows

What I want to know is do the describe blocks return a promise I can sync with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to utilize [`jasmine-beforeAll`](https://github.com/nonplus/jasmine-beforeAll) plugin which provides `beforeAll()` and `afterAll()` hooks which are basically spec-level setup and teardown functions:

```
describe('My spec', function () {
  beforeAll(function() { doMyAction(); });
  afterAll(function() { doAnotherAction(); });

  describe('My sub spec 1', function () {
    ...
  });

  describe('My sub spec 2', function () {
    ...
  });
});
```

In this case the execution order would be:

- doMyAction
- describe1
- describe2
- doAnotherAction

FYI, `beforeAll()` and `afterAll()` are currently [a part of jasmine development version](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown), relevant feature request:

- [Support for beforeAll and afterAll](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/pull/56)

---

Another option would be to call `doMyAction` and `doAnotherAction` from the `it` blocks before and after the sub specs:

```
describe('My spec', function () {
    it('beforeAll', function () {
        doMyAction();
    });

    describe('My sub spec 1', function () {
        ...
    });

    describe('My sub spec 2', function () {
        ...
    });

    it('afterAll', function () {
        doAnotherAction();
    });
});
```

Comment: The protractor project does not include the main development version of jasmine but the version 1.2. I'll accept your second option, even if I consider it as a hack.